# Focus event on CTabFolder selection

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am trying to create a SWT Application using `CTabFolder`. This `CTabFolder` contains multiple `CTabItem` and each `CTabItem` contains treeviewer therein. My requirement is when I select a particular `CTabItem`, the first node of treeviewer underneat this selected `CTabFolder` should be selected by default. Can anyone please help on this. Thanks, tor

Comment: I doubt that you get any answer here when you dont have any question. Maybe you can specify your needs more closely. Maybe in terms of a "real question"?

Answer (score 4):

First, add a `SelectionListener` to your `CTabFolder`.

On the listener's `widgetSelected` method, you can access the `CTabItem` selected using the `item` attibute of the received argument.